# Is extending an annotation interface meaningless and discouraged?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations

Here's an example of it in the JavaDoc of [AnnotationLiteral](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/util/AnnotationLiteral.html) e.g.

> "An instance of an annotation type may be obtained by subclassing AnnotationLiteral."

```
public abstract class PayByQualifier extends AnnotationLiteral<PayBy> implements PayBy {
}

PayBy paybyCheque = new PayByQualifier() {
    public PaymentMethod value() {
        return CHEQUE;
    }
};
```

There is a more complete example in Section 5.6.3 in the [CDI spec](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr346/).

> **5.6.3. Using AnnotationLiteral and TypeLiteral**
>
> javax.enterprise.util.AnnotationLiteral makes it easier to specify qualifiers when calling select():

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE})
public @interface Synchronous {}

@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE})
public @interface PayBy {
    PaymentMethod value();
    @Nonbinding String comment() default "";
}

public PaymentProcessor getSynchronousPaymentProcessor(PaymentMethod paymentMethod) {
    class SynchronousQualifier extends AnnotationLiteral<Synchronous>
        implements Synchronous {}
    class PayByQualifier extends AnnotationLiteral<PayBy>
        implements PayBy {
        public PaymentMethod value() { return paymentMethod; }
    }
    return anyPaymentProcessor.select(new SynchronousQualifier(), new PayByQualifier()).get();
}
```

And finally according to section 9.6 of the [Java annotation types spec.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6):

> Unless explicitly modified herein, all of the rules that apply to normal interface declarations apply to annotation type declarations.
>
> For example, annotation types share the same namespace as normal class and interface types; and annotation type declarations are legal wherever interface declarations are legal, and have the same scope and accessibility.

However, the Java compiler complains when I attempt to implement an annotation.  In particular, Intellij warns:

> "Reports any classes declared as implementing or extending an annotation interface. While it is legal to extend an annotation interfaces, IT IS NEARLY MEANINGLESS, AND DISCOURAGED." (emphasis mine).

Here is the error message as displayed from within Intellij:

[image: Screen capture from within Intellij]

The Intellij warning seems to contradict the official Java documentation.  I presume the Intellij warning is based upon a warning that comes from the Java compiler.  What is correct?  The Intellij and/or compiler warning or the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Intellij support:

> "We can change warning text for example to: "While it is legal to extend an annotation interface it is often done by accident, and the result won't be usable as an annotation." Note that you can always suppress the warning for the statement."

My response:

> The proposed solution... would require developers to always suppress the warning for the statement.  This solution is poor because the code would be littered with @SuppressWarning or, worse, the developer would need to turn off the warning altogether. The best and most useful solution, would be to not display any warning whatsoever if the developer extends AnnotationLiteral or TypeLiteral and implements an @interface at the same time.

A [YouTrack Issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-134433) was filed.

Comment: From Intellij support on December 17, 2014: _Fixed for AnnotationLiteral, but not for TypeLiteral which should not implement @interface._

Comment: Fixed in build 140.1181

Answer (score 1):

Annotations types are used as meta data. The typical use case for annotations, at runtime, is with reflection. You annotate something, then you use reflection to retrieve the annotation, process it, and possibly enhance the target. The annotation instances are created and given to you by the JVM through calls to the reflection API.

In that regard, creating your own annotation type instances, which `AnnotationLiteral` makes easier to do, is kind of pointless since you have no target, since nothing was actually annotated.

It can be useful for cases where you need to mock an annotation type instance or you want to inject some functionality that only exists when processing annotations.

Intellij is simply warning you that it's uncommon.

Comment: Read section 5.6 of the CDI spec. and you'll understand that this question is about programmatic lookup, useful when bean types or qualifiers vary dynamically at runtime, or when one needs to iterate over all beans of a certain type, or etc. There is a target and something is annotated: `@Any Instance<PaymentProcessor>`. It's not uncommon to do programmatic lookup and even if it is uncommon warning that it's "nearly meaningless and discouraged" seems inaccurate at best. Not sure your "typical" use case even applies here, as the question does not seek to know or understand how annotations work.

Comment: @PatrickGarner [`Instance#select(..)`](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.0/javax/enterprise/inject/Instance.html#select(java.lang.annotation.Annotation...)) is a way to imitate annotation based injection. You pass a type of the injection target and instances of annotations that describe that target. That's what I meant by _you want to inject some functionality that only exists when processing annotations_. (Perhaps the _only_ was misleading.)

Comment: @PatrickGarner The common use case is to annotate something. In the examples in the spec about `AnnotationLiteral`, nothing is annotated. But you want to achieve the same behavior. The developers of Intellij must have thought that it'd be important to warn you about this.

Comment: I guess I was confused when you said _creating your own annotation type instances... is kind of **pointless**... since **nothing** was actually annotated._ That threw me off because I knew that Instance was annotated. To say that the spec. and the Java API is doing something that is _pointless_ (your word), _meaningless_ and should be _discouraged_ (Intellij's words) is confusing. I'm trying to wrap my head around this but unfortunately I'm no closer to understanding it at this point. How can it be _uncommon_ or _meaningless_ if the API provides the means and the spec. provides the examples?

Comment: @PatrickGarner I should emphasize the _kind of_ :). The warning might be a little too serious. This API found this trick (instantiating annotation types) and decided to apply it to solve a problem. To be honest, it's the first I've ever seen this done. In this valid case, you should just ignore the warnings. Intellij might actually have a `@SuppressWarnings` for it.